# What are the inhabitants of Golarion called?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, lore, pathfinder-2e, starfinder

Like the inhabitants of Earth are called Earthlings, what are the inhabitants of Golarion called?  Golarions?  Golarian? Something completely different?

Comment: "bags of XP" comes to mind 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is **Golarian**

This information, as far as I know, is not present in any of the book published until now but we can be pretty sure on Golarian since this term is given to us directly from a developer (Mark Moreland to be specific).

> Golarian is the adjective form of the proper noun.

Source: [Mark Moreland answer](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs2tlek?Using-Names-of-Places-from-Pathfinder-in-a#7)